# how to retrieve serialize data into tabel in php using unserialized

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, serialization

Greeting, My name is Tri. I am working on serialize data into database in mysql php. but after i serialized my data into database, i don't know how to retrieve it into table using unserialized. 
after i unserialized data from database, the data converted into array when i use  `print_r();` method.

this is my code :

```
    $cart_id = 9;
    $sql = "SELECT details FROM shop WHERE id_order =".$cart_id;
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows()>0){
        foreach ($result->result_array() as $row) {
            $cart = unserialize($row['details']);
        }

        echo '<pre>';
        echo print_r($cart);
        echo '</pre>';
```

> i stored serialized data into column details inside orders table.

but when i try retrieve serialized colum details using unserialized, i just can show all of them using print_r().

this is the `print_r()` result code after i unserialized it :

```
Array
(
    [c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
            [id] => 1
            [qty] => 4
            [name] => Polo Shirt
            [price] => 15
            [subtotal] => 60
        )

)
```

My question is, how i can display it into table per item?

Comment: do you want to display the data on the web page in the form of table.?

Comment: You can use `foreach()` to loop through the array, and echo/print it out along with the appropriate table tags.

Comment: Can you give me the example please @Nick Coons

Comment: @RaghavGarg yes i want to display in twble

Comment: I posted an example for you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and request for an example, this should get you started:

```
if ( $result->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        echo '<table>';

        foreach ( $result->result_array() as $row ) {
            echo '<tr>';

            $cart = unserialize( $row['details'] );

            echo '<td>' . $cart['rowid'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $cart['id'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $cart['qty'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $cart['name'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $cart['price'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $cart['subtotal'] . '</td>';

            echo '</tr>';
        }

        echo '</table>';
    }
}
```

Comment: The error still shows like this **Message: Undefined index: rowid**

Comment: it seems rowid, name,,qty,price, and sub total read as variable and can't find it when trying to display using foreach method.

Comment: This is just an example. I don't know what your full array looks like it, so I can't say for sure what the indexes should be. You'll need to modify it for your actual array structure.

Comment: anyway, thanks Master @Nick Coons. I apreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
public function shop($id_order) {

    $data = array();

    $query = $this->db->get_where($this->db->dbprefix . 'shop', array('cart_id' => $id_order));

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $setting) {
            $data = unserialize($setting['details']);
        }
    }

    return $data;
}

public function index() {
    $results = $this->shop(9);

    $data['details'] = array();

    foreach ($results as $result)
    {
        $data['details'][] = array(
            'rowid' => $result['rowid'],
            'id' => $result['id'],
            'qty' => $result['qty'],
            'name' => $result['name'],
            'price' => $result['price'],
            'subtotal' => $result['subtotal']
        );
    }

    $this->load->view('someview', $data);
}
```

Also good to read this

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

View

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($details as $detail) {?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $detail['id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $detail['qty'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $detail['name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $detail['price'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $detail['subtotal'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php }?>
</tbody>
```